# VPN save Bandwidth?

Tags: vpn, dns, bandwidth, intranet

is it possible to setup your VPN so that only sites hosted on the VPN use its bandwidth? For example, if someone connected to my VPN, how would I stop them watching loads of YouTube videos and wasting all of the bandwidth?

Thanks again,
Francis

Comment: This question makes no sense.

Comment: If she connects through your VPN, it means she was given the credentials necessary to log into it. Thus she is authorized.

Comment: How could I make only specific kinds of traffic go through the VPN? DNS queries for example. And then make requests for videos, images etc ... go outside the VPN to save bandwidth?